# How can i fix when CSS indentation is not working in all browsers?

Tags: html, css, indentation

i need to make a design as following:

```
   Total Maximum Daily Load, EPA
```

- Modeling the Fate and Transport of Pollutants
- Total Maximum Daily Load (TMDL) Development

as you see the "Total Maximum daily load" needs to be aligned with the bullet points "modelling.." and "total..".

the required align shows up in internet explorer and firefox, but in chrome it shows as below

```
 Total Maximum Daily Load, EPA
```

- Modeling the Fate and Transport of Pollutants
- Total Maximum Daily Load (TMDL) Development

"Total Maximum daily load" is not aligned with "modeling" and "total" of the bullet points, why does it work in one browser and not in other? How can i make this indentation browser independent.

Comment: Look into list-style-position - http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/list-style-position

Comment: And use a CSS Reset - http://www.cssreset.com/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/GxVgx/4/

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is probably to make the first text an item of the list but without a bullet:

```
<ul>
<li style="list-style: none">Total Maximum Daily Load, EPA
<li>Modeling the Fate and Transport of Pollutants
<li>Total Maximum Daily Load (TMDL) Development
</ul>
```

An alternative solution is to remove all margins and padding from `ul` and `li` (it’s browser differences here that cause the issue) and then set a left margin for the `ul` and an identical left margin on the first text. Note that this removes default vertical margin from `ul`, so you may wish to add them, in addition to tuning the left margin value. (A value of `1.3em` or so is probably the smallest safe value, safe in the sense that the list bullets will fit in.)

```
<style>
ul, li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul, .list-header {
  margin-left: 1.3em;
}
</style>
<div class="list-header">Total Maximum Daily Load, EPA</div>
<ul>
<li>Modeling the Fate and Transport of Pollutants
<li>Total Maximum Daily Load (TMDL) Development
</ul>
```

Comment: That div is pretending to be a headline element.